# Voltage follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

I designed the circuit , but I don't understand part e). how can I use voltage follower in these two circuits ? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not wanting to answer homework outright, I would suggest re-reading a section on the ideal op-amp to understand what is being asked in section (e).  The Voltage follower circuit is really simple to draw, but you have to understand the op amp input/output ideal behaviour to understand how it works.  Hopefully in section (d) the voltage changed at Va and Vc to a new value, did you understand why that happened?  So question (e) wants you to use a voltage-follower to restore Va to it's original value.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A voltage follower can be made with a transistor or an op-amp, in this case I assume an op-amp would be better here.

Use an op-amp in a voltage follower arrangement, (+ pin as input with the output pin looped back to - input pin).  If this does not make sense read up on basic op-amp circuits.

Your simulator may setup the op-amp power pins and gnd for you, if not you'd need to look up the power pins and make the connections manually.